# Template methods in ruby

Tags: ruby, generics

Simple question:

In java you can define :

```
void myFunction<T>(T value) { //do stuff }
```

Is there an equivalent in ruby, and if not, how can I achieve a similar result (passing class types?)

Comment: Ruby is dynamic type, it makes little sense to pass the class type. What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have some static classes, which have some static methods and I want to specify which static class to be used when calling the method

Comment: Generics aka parametric polymorphism are a feature of static type systems. Ruby doesn't have a static type system. The very idea makes no sense at all. Likewise your question about class types. There are no types in Ruby. You cannot pass them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a class to a method just like passing normal objects. For example

```
def create_object(klass, *args)
  klass.new(*args)
end

create_object(String)  #=> ""
create_object(Hash)  #=> {}
create_object(Array, 3, :hello)  #=> [:hello, :hello, :hello]
```

Answer (score 4):

First a few definitions

- Generics is an abstraction over types
- Polymorphism is a sum-type pattern
- Composition is a product-type pattern
- Most OO languages lean towards polymorphism

Ruby is an OO language. Polymorphism is at the core of its design. The type system in Ruby is only getting strong in Ruby 3. So we may see more interesting generics at that point; but until now, I haven't heard that to be a feature.

To achieve this, we technically need to figure out a way of *applying a method on separate types without knowing the type*. It's a lot of code duplication is possible.

Your Java example…

```java
void myFunction<T>(T value) { //do stuff }
```

…can be translated into Ruby as

```rb
def myFunction(value)
  raise "Only works with T types" unless value.is_a? T
  # do stuff
end
```

Where the magic now has to happen is in defining the possible set of `T`. I'm thinking something like…

```rb
class T
  def _required_for_MyFunction()
    raise "T is abstract!"
  end
end

class Something < T
  def _required_for_MyFunction()
    # does something
  end
end

class Nothing < T
  def _required_for_MyFunction()
    # does nothing
  end
end
```

The painful part of polymorphism is that you have to define your type space from the get-go. The good parts of this is you have total control of the domain space.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby follows [duck typing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). You can pass arguments of any class to any method (which is the original reason why you might need generics). If you want to get the class of said argument, you can still use `#class`

```
def foo(bar)
  bar.class
end

foo 'baz' # => String
foo 42 # => Fixnum
```

Comment: I'm no doctor, so I doubt I need geneTics ;)

Comment: @MarioStoilov, I was writing that during lunch on my phone. Autocorrect :)